# Measure of urban-ness or city density

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, urban-economics

I have a dependent variable I want to examine in relation to a measure of city density. This means city population as well as geographical spread. Ideally, it would also include a measure of neighborhood clustering, or there might be a separate measure for this to use as a different regression variable. It doesn't have to be a single number - it could be a 2-tuple. I haven't learned of formal variables with associated theory for this (like Gini coefficient) so I'm wondering if there are any, because then there might be data sets already constructed that I can use with my dependent variable data set.